# ReactJS Show alert when user leaves the current browser tab

Tags: reactjs, stack, fullscreen, anti-cheat

I would like to lock users on the page. The users can go on other tabs or desktop at least when they click on other tab of browser I would like to show them alert dialog which say "Are you sure?"

Comment: Have you tried loading your page in a separate iframe?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I'd close your page and never come back if you try to pull that sh*t on me.

Comment: I am trying to build exam web site thats why I want to lock you on page . when you try go out it will submit your answer and you wont come back again

Comment: you cannot block users from using their browser. if you want to do something like that you'll need a standalone application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys Thanks for helping

I find code which is I need :

```
  requestFullscreen = () => {
    if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
      document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    }
  };
```

then I called this function onClick event on Button. After that I will check when User try to left page (alt+f4, alt+tab .. etc) I will show alert for "Are you sure for left page "